# Error "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap" while trying to setContent to a QDomDocument

Tags: xml, qt, c++17, qdomdocument

When Debugging my solution an exception is thrown at the end of the deallocate (QArrayData) function. The output shows me this :
HEAP[MappingMidi.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 000001C0B6DB0000, 000001C0BB383860 )
MappingMidi.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

I am developping an application using Qt 6.3.2 on Visual Studio 2019. I want to read the data of a xml file and to do so I am using the QDomDocument library ; In Properties->Qt Project Setting->Qt Modules I added "xml".
The code that throws the exception is this :

```
    QDomDocument xml;
    QFile mappingData(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/mappingData.xml");
    if (!mappingData.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        return;
    }

    QString errorMsg;
    int errorLine = 0;
    int errorColumn = 0;
    if (!xml.setContent(&mappingData, &errorMsg, &errorLine, &errorColumn)) {
        qDebug() << errorMsg;
        qDebug() << errorLine;
    }
    
    mappingData.close();
```

In debug mode I figgured out it's the setContent that throws the exception, because when I only initialize `QDomDocument xml` it works fine so I assume that it's not a problem of importing the xml library but it comes from somewhere else triggered by the setContent method.

Comment: There are a few things to check: 
Is the XML file syntax correct? Is the XML file size too big? Do you get the same error when you isolate this part of the code?